# How to integrate different modules of an android project to a one single complete working application?k?

Tags: android

I have 4 teams 4 member each, each team is working on a different module of the same android application.**It is a confidential application of the company so none of the team is aware that they are working on the same application .** when these teams completes the given modules **my task is to integrate all the modules,**
So what kind of tools can I use to do the same? **How to integrate the modules to a one single complete working application?**

Comment: Just create a multi-module project and let them deliver library modules... but if they're working on different parts of the same one application module, then you'll have to manually merge them.

Comment: You wants to do it on manually..

Comment: you can use github for this assign task to each one and than you can marge it all modules at a time

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple Android Application Modules Under One Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25676432/multiple-android-application-modules-under-one-project)